# email from SQL server are wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and am trying to send emails to customers about their overdue ADV returns.  There is a 30 day, 45 day and 50 day letter. I have noticed this issue currently on the 30 day and 45 day letters.

I have a query that pulls the right people. For instance on the 30 day letter today it pulled 4 records and they are correct. for instance the data looks like

```
john   item1
david  item1
david  item2
fred   item1
```

So what is happening is I get 4 emails, but john is missing and david gets 3 emails one of which is a duplicate.

Here is the code for sending the emails

```
OPEN C1

FETCH NEXT FROM C1 
INTO @sronum, @transdate,@item,@desc, @days, @email, @NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 
    INTO @sronum, @transdate,@item,@desc,@days, @email, @NAME

    set @email = 'internal test email address'
    set @subject = 'ADV Return is 30 days past due'
    set @body = 'Dear ' + @name + ', </br></br>'  + more text

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @recipients = @email
         ,@Body = @Body
         ,@subject = @Subject
         ,@body_format = 'html'
         ,@exclude_query_output = 1
END

CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
```

Comment: You're fetching twice before you send the first email.

Comment: Move the second `FETCH NEXT ...` *after* the `sp_send_dbmail` statement.

Comment: ok I see what I did wrong now.  I had tried to move the 2nd Fetch earlier, but got error messages.  What I did not move earlier was both lines the Fetch and the variable line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit commented;

```sql
OPEN C1

-- Fetch first result and throw it away since next fetch will be done
-- before using the values
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
     @sronum, @transdate,@item,@desc, @days, @email, @NAME

-- If the fetch went well, loop
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 -- Fetch the next row and ignore if it went well for now
 FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
     @sronum, @transdate,@item,@desc,@days, @email, @NAME
 set @email = 'internal test email address'
 set @subject = 'ADV Return is 30 days past due'
 set @body = 'Dear ' + @name + ', </br></br>'  + more text

 -- Send a mail to the possibly valid address
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @recipients = @email
  ,@Body = @Body
  ,@subject = @Subject
  ,@body_format = 'html'
  ,@exclude_query_output = 1

-- Jump back to the start of the loop to check if the mail just sent 
-- was supposed to be sent.
END
CLOSE C1

DEALLOCATE C1
```

The simplest fix is to move the second fetch after the email has been sent. That will check if the first result was valid, send a mail, fetch a new row and go back to the validity check to possibly send another mail.